# PHP - reading emails limited on certain date

Tags: php, imap

I'm using the ImapParsers class for PHP to read the emails in PHP.
Everything works well, but now I cannot read after 6 march and when I enter my inbox I receive new emails every day.

```
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);


        $output.= 'Name:  '.$overview[0]->from.'</br>';
            $output.= 'Email:  '.$overview[0]->message_id.'</br>';



    }

    echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

does someone know what can be a problem?

Comment: are you receiving brand new mail? or new mail tacked on to your conversation threads?

Comment: im reciving new emails for the same person with the same title, just the date and attachment is different

Comment: so are these replies? I ask because if they are from the same person; and the same subject.. are they replies to a conversational thread? If so; it does not matter if the date or body content is different; if this these are indeed replies; and this was an original, archived conversation; then it does not count as "new" email.

Comment: no, its not reply, its new email